# Update JSON with refreshInterval

Tags: json

I want to update every 10 seconds json data.
With this function crashes the script.
Is there a better way?

```
$(function refreshUsers() {
    $.getJSON('/api/TrainlocationList/', function (loadscale) {
        $(loadscale).each(function (i, item) {
            $(item).each(function (i, Type) {
                $('#LabelID').html(Type.TrainLocationName);
                var refreshInterval = setInterval(refreshUsers, 10 * 1000);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('/api/TrainlocationList/', function (loadscale) {
        $(loadscale).each(function (i, item) {
            $(item).each(function (i, Type) {
                $('#LabelID').html(Type.TrainLocationName);
            });
        });
    });
}, 10000)
```

Comment: looks good! it runs every second again. what after a few hours loading a new role? withe te first example my browser crashed after 10 min :(

Comment: I have updated it to every 10 seconds now.  You could keep an eye on it with chrome tools, or maybe look at using `SignalR`?

Comment: @user2385302, if this worked, you can upvote to help others with the same issue.